# Excel VBA Change last two digits of a number

Tags: vba, numbers

I´m trying to make a number to change its last two digits to zero.

In Excel, in a certain Cell I will always get for sure a number always higher than 100. Let´s assume that I get the number 26312. What I want is to the number to be changed for 26300. Another example, if I get the number 14920,

I want to be changed to 14900. I would like to post some code but the truth is that I´m not succeding in anything. I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

Done it!

I used this:

```
Range("U19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(R[-12]C[-1])=5,LEFT(R[-12]C[-1],3)&""00"")+0"
```

I want the cell change to appear in U19. The cell containing the original number is in T7